# How to send my products to this function? Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am trying to get the fetched results that cames with the item I click. Here is the code so far:

```
export const fetchProducts = createAsyncThunk(
  'products/fetchProducts',
  async (id, { dispatch }) => {
    return axios.get(`https://api-test-carrinho.herokuapp.com/product/business/${id}`
    ).then(resp => {
      dispatch(addProducts(resp.data)) //When I dispatch to addProduct, comes the values but Products only warning the results but actually shows empty.
    })
  }
)

const productsAdapter = createEntityAdapter({
  selectId: (item) => item._id
});

const productsSlice = createSlice({
  name: "products",
  initialState: productsAdapter.getInitialState({ loading: false }),
  reducers: {
    addProduct: productsAdapter.addOne,
    addProducts: productsAdapter.addMany,
  },
  extraReducers: {
    [fetchProducts.pending](state){
      state.loading = true
    },
    [fetchProducts.fulfilled](state, { payload }){
      state.loading = false
      productsAdapter.setAll(state, payload)
    }
  }
});

export default productsSlice.reducer;

export const { addProduct, addProducts } = productsSlice.actions;

export const productSelectors = productsAdapter.getSelectors(
  (state) => state.products
);

export const {
  selectById: selectProductById,
  selectAll: selectAllProducts
} = productSelectors;
```

When I use the selector:

```
const products = useSelector(state => state.products)
```

And here is how I pass the id of the current business so I can fetch depending of the business I clicked. I used onClick={() => getProducts(item._id)} to pass the id

```
function getProducts(id){
    dispatch(fetchProducts(id))
    console.log('add', id);
  }

   useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchProducts())
  }, [])
```

Here is the warning:

```
The entity passed to the `selectId` implementation returned undefined. You should probably provide your own `selectId` implementation. The entity that was passed: (2) [{…}, {…}]0: {deleted: false, activated: true, _id: "609f02e5c553f3b20731de32", name: "sashimi", category: "Sushi", …}1: {deleted: false, activated: true, _id: "609f02f7c553f3b20731de33", name: "Sushi", category: "Sushi", …}length: 2__proto__: Array(0) The `selectId` implementation: item => item._id
```

I am stuck with this. Any other solution to make a shopping cart with redux? I need to get the products depending on the business I click. I used other ways and worked but when I tried to increase the amount, it just duplicates.